# FFMpeg on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg, xcode7

I'm trying to learn FFMpeg through this tutorial: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html

I was hoping that just translating the C code to swift should get me up and running but I guess I was mistaken

I tried converting the following code:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;
// Open video file
if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, 0, NULL)!=0) {}
```

to:

```
let pFormatCtx : UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<AVFormatContext>> = nil
// Open video file
if avformat_open_input(pFormatCtx, path, nil, opaque) != 0 {}
```

This code breaks at: **if avformat_open_input(pFormatCtx, path, nil, opaque) != 0 {}** With an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error

can anyone guess whats wrong here??

By the way I have the FFMpeg library compiling without an issue so I don't think there might be an issue with the way I compiled or imported it. I'm probably passing wrong arguments I think :/ Any guesses??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off I'm using Swift 2 with xCode 7.2 ...

The solution was to create the format Context as an **"UnsafeMutablePointer< AVFormatContext >"** and then pass its address through the **avformat_open_input** method. Here's the code that worked for me:

```
var formatContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<AVFormatContext>()

if avformat_open_input(&formatContext, path, nil, nil) != 0 {
    print("Couldn't open file")
    return
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's a similar solution to mine (you are using a mutable `var` variable), whereas I use a `let` constant. Prepending the `&` to the variable as you did should create the same thing.

Comment: Hello there, can you please give me the url of your library you used to get the FFMPEG library working for your project?

Comment: https://github.com/chrisballinger/FFmpeg-iOS I've used this one but you can compile it yourself as well using this script: https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

Answer (score 1):

The partial solution & background explanation can be found here: http://en.swifter.tips/pointer-memory/.

Basically, the UnsafeMutablePointer must be `allocated` before being used.

To make the code above work, try this:

```
let path = ...

let formatContext = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<AVFormatContext>>.alloc(1)

if (avformat_open_input(formatContext, path, nil, nil) != 0) {
    // TODO: Error handling
}
```

When you are done, do not forget to call `formatContext.destroy()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had completely forgotten about this. I tried this solution but it doesn't work (still the same error on the same line). I'll post the solution that worked for me here in a bit.